# Google Analytics conversion tracking with a pixel?

Tags: google-analytics, tracking

Right now I can only see that the only way to track conversion through Google Analytics is with Goals.

And it only allows entering the thankyou page URL.

In my case, I track registrations, and I don't use a thank you page.

When user lands on my homepage, clicks on Social Login button and after Sign in they land on the homepage again (but now logged in).

I use a Wordpress widget that appears when the user is loggged in. And this is how I track conversions.

But for this, I need a Google Analytics conversion pixel.

So my question is, is it possible, and does Google Analytics have a conversion (goal) tracking pixel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send an **event** to Analytics when user is logged, so you can set that event as conversion.